# Cannot subscript a value of type 'Set<String>' with an index of type 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, set

I am having a Set of Strings which have some data in it. 
But when I was showing data from the set to the tableView, in cellForRowAtIndexPath method it gives me above stated error.
Here is my Code:

```
var tradeSet: Set<String> = ["TKAI", "YNDX", "PSTG"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyTrade", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTradeTableViewCell

    let objects = tradeSet[indexPath.row]
    cell.tradeName.text = objects

    return cell
}
```

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: A `Set` is an unordered collection type and cannot be subscripted by index.

Comment: You have to convert set to array.

Comment: @vadian Well *technically* it can be subscripted by index, just a `SetIndex`, not an `Int` ;)

Comment: @AshishKakkad It worked I  just convert Set to Array.

Comment: @Hamish Right, *...cannot be subscripted by **integer** index*

Answer (score 2):

A set is not **indexable**, because the order in which the elements of a set are listed is irrelevant. You should be storing your elements in an array or a different data structure. You could do something quick like the following (Not recommended):

```
var tradeSet: Set<String> = ["TKAI", "YNDX", "PSTG"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyTrade", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTradeTableViewCell

    // This is not the best data structure for this job tho
    for (index, element) in tradeSet.enumerated() {
        if row == index {
            cell.tradeName.text = element
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

These kind of scenarios suggest incorrect data structure/algorithm.

Comment: *"A set is not indexable, because it has no order"* – That is wrong or at least misleading. A `Set` is a collection, each element has an index and it can be subscripted. The order of the elements in a set is *unspecified.*

Comment: @MartinR Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the Set to an array for your requirement.
To convert a set to an array ,

```
var tradeSet: Set<String> = ["TKAI", "YNDX", "PSTG"]    
let stringArray = Array(tradeSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 way :

1. Array(tradeSet)[indexPath.row]
2. tradeSet.enumerated().first{(index , value) in index == indexPath.row}!.element